# How to set Edge or Chrome to open with DevTools already activated from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

So I do quite a bit of web development using Visual Studio, therefore my web app will launch using Edge each time I am debugging, but I still have to manually open the DevTools. Is there a way from Visual Studio to set Edge or Chrome to launch with DevTools already opened to save me time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're a few steps for you. It worked for me:

**Step 1:**
[image]Select it.

**Step 2:**

[image]

Select `Browser With...`.

**Step 3:**

[image]

Select `Add...`.

**Step 4:**

[image]

In `Program`, enter your Edge executable path. If you are not sure, you can find it in `Edge://version`.

In `Arguments`, use `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs --user-data-dir=c:\your\another profile`. If an Edge instance is kept open when you debug your application, devtools may not be opened. So, another profile is suggested.

In `Friendly name`, choose a descriptive name for this preference.

PS: You can also set this preference as default for convenience.